# need help to export table from sql server 2008 to text file

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, syntax-error, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a table present in ms sql server 2008 to a text file on my system.
I am writing the following command in sql server query window

```
SELECT *
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[AddressType] 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Now whenever I write this command the sql help gives me error  that `incorrect syntax near 'INTO'`

then I tried interchanging from and into keywords as follows

```
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM [AdventureWorks].[Person].[AddressType] ;
```

Now it gives me error that `incorrect syntax near 'C:/filename.csv'`

Please help me regarding this.
I am not able to remove these error and get a working sql

Answer (score 6):

There are more than many ways to solve a problem , In this case here are two solutions

**Solution 1**

- Right Click over the Database name -> Tasks -> Export Data
- Choose the table as Data Source
- Choose Flat file destination as destination
- Choose a File-name ( any file name )
- Mark "Column Names in the first data row" ( this is opitional)

And that's it.

**Solution 2**

```
DECLARE  
 @saveas VARCHAR(2048)
,@query VARCHAR(2048)
,@bcpquery VARCHAR(2048)
,@bcpconn VARCHAR(64)
,@bcpdelim VARCHAR(2)

 SET @query      = 'select * from table1'
 SET @saveas     = '\\SERVER1\SHARE1\FOLDER\QueryOutput.txt'
 SET @bcpdelim   = '|'
 SET @bcpconn    = '-T' -- Trusted
 --SET @bcpconn    = '-U <username> -P <password>' -- SQL authentication


 SET @bcpquery = 'bcp "' + replace(@query, char(10), '') + '" QUERYOUT "' + @saveas + '" -c -t^' + @bcpdelim + ' ' + @bcpconn + ' -S ' + @@servername
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpquery
```

Comment: got this error while trying to execute the slotion that you suggested Microtechie "Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell', see "Surface Area Configuration" in SQL Server Books Online.
"

Comment: i need to migrate data from SQL server 2008 to teradata databse,so i need a query to export data to a text file or any other file,then i will use this file to load data into teradata database,and i have to repeatedly execute this query for all the tables of the sql database

Answer (score 1):

To solved the error "SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server." first do this.

-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE;
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE;
GO

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190693.aspx