# Copy SQL Server table records into a text file?

Tags: sql-server-2012

How to copy all records of one table from a SQL Server database into a text file?
I need to send one table records to another person, how can I do it

Comment: did you get a chance to look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781896/need-help-to-export-table-from-sql-server-2008-to-text-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to give data to another person then create backup(with data/without data or only schema) or create script then shared to that person else you can export to excel also

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321052/how-to-get-script-of-sql-server-data)

Answer (score 1):

Just setup the option of "results to text" (Hit Ctrl + T) Or "results to file "(Ctrl +shift + f)