# How to store a tabe in a text file on a day -to- day basis

Tags: sql-server

I need to Store the order Details table in a text File On a day-to- day basis. 
Please what tools do i need to perform the data transfer.
Thanks

Comment: It might be a SQL Agent job that you are after. Please refer to : [How to: Schedule a Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191439%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Right Click over the Database name ->

Tasks -> Export Data

Choose the table as Data Source

Choose Flat file destination as destination

Choose a File-name ( any file name )

Mark "Column Names in the first data row" ( this is opitional)

And that's it.

[need help to export table from sql server 2008 to text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781896/need-help-to-export-table-from-sql-server-2008-to-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `SQL Server job`, and schedule it to run every day. Inside your SQL Job, you can write your query like following.

```
sqlcmd -i c:\sql\query.sql -o c:\sql\output.txt
```

Note: query.sql is a file which should have your SQL query like following.

```
SELECT * FROM [YOU_TABLE]
```

You can get more details here.

[Create a Job in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job)